# jQuery: How to smooth animated image resizing

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate, image-resizing

I'm a jQuery noob - so please excuse the probable basicness of this question.

I'm doing something pretty simple - on hover animate the position and size of an image. When you mouse over the images there are some noticeable 'jaggies' (in FF, chrome, safari and that other crappy browser) - is there a way to get rid of this? The jquery code is as follows and a live link is here [kristechdev.metropoliscreative.com](http://kristechdev.metropoliscreative.com) (hover over the icons).

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#zoomNav li img').hoverIntent(

     function() {

      $(this).animate({'margin-top' :'-35px', 'margin-left' :'-10px', 'height' :'95px','width' : '79px' }, 
            'fast');
     }, 

     function() {

      $(this).animate({'margin-top' : '0px', 'margin-left' :'0px', 'height' :'70px','width' : '58px' }, 
            'fast');
    });    
   });



</script>
```

Comment: Just checked your link and the animation is smooth in my browser.  I don't see an issue.

Comment: ha... maybe im just nuts... :)

Answer (score 0):

Might need to [enable interpolation on images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530822(VS.85).aspx) inside IE, if that's where the issue is.

Comment: issue happens in FF, safari, chrome - havent checked opera but who uses that? :) - thanks!

Comment: @nikibrown -  see stats... http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp some are still using opera...

Comment: ***Edit* a friend did a quick screencast of the animation in slow mode (see 30 second mark) see the jaggies?**

http://www.duzodesign.com/junk/kristech/kristech.htm